# Как создать Label в большом количестве tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Имеется задача: сделать окно с кнопкой, по клику на которую можно будет создать новый `tkinter.Label()` , причем количество не ограничено. Итак, с окном и прочим я разберусь сам, но как написать такой скрипт, чтобы он генерировал новые `tkinter.Label()` с уникальными названиями(необязательно)? Прошу дать просто направление и ссылочку на теорию или кусочек кода с объяснением(необязательно), пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать компоновщик `place(x, y)` и в зависимости от расположения виджетов прибавлять координаты

```
import tkinter


class Main(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number_y = 50
        self.number = 0
        tkinter.Label(self, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number)).place(x=0, y=self.number_y)
        tkinter.Button(self, text='Press', command=self.func).place(x=0, y=0, w=100)

    def func(self):
        self.number_y += 20
        self.number += 1
        tkinter.Label(self, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number)).place(x=0, y=self.number_y)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

или через `pack()` добавлять по очереди виджеты

```
import tkinter


class Main(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = 0
        tkinter.Button(self, text='Press', command=self.func).pack()
        tkinter.Label(self, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number)).pack()

    def func(self):
        self.number += 1
        tkinter.Label(self, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот как сделать 20 надписей с цифрами от 1 до 20 в цикле фор:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

for i in range(0,20):
    globals()["lab"+str(i)] = Label(root, text=i+1)
    globals()["lab"+str(i)].pack()
```

к ним можно будет обратиться по именам lab0, lab1... lab19

Comment: Очень плохая идея, не нужно так делать. Нумерованные переменные не нужны - вместо них используйте списки.